# Enlightened badge not showing up

Tags: support, badges

I think I have achieved the criteria for the badge on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/317680/how-to-sort-an-excel-spreadsheet-columns-by-row-contents/317682#317682) question, and I have waited about an hour. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Enlightened" badge is defined as "First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes."  Since you're the only one to answer, and you have 10 upvotes, and your answer was accepted, you do meet all of the criteria.

So, here's what I think is going on...

You have to wait a while before you will receive this badge because there is a short period of time where users can change their votes.  Once this timeout has expired, and those votes are permanently locked in, I suspect you'll get that *then* you'll get your badge.

Good question (+1).

(If anyone knows the timeout for votes to get locked in, please add it in a comment and I'll upvote your comment.  Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Congratulations!  Now I'm wondering whether my suspicion is correct.

Comment: I would assume so.

Answer (score 1):

You have been awarded the badge

https://superuser.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=82812

Comment: It just happened, see comment to previous answer.